# date picker 12 hrs format in android

Tags: android

how to get 12 hrs format date picker with AM_PM value. Actualy when i am picking the date from date picker dialog it is coming in 24hrs format and AM_Pm is not coming.
please help

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean on the TimePicker. It has a method called

```
public void setIs24HourView (Boolean is24HourView)
```

set it false.

Also if you are using the TimePickerDialog you can just pass false to the last argument of any constructor.